# AWS Kubernetes: Selecting SSL Certificate on AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, amazon-elb

I’m trying to configure SSL for an AWS Load Balancer for my AWS EKS cluster. The load balancer is proxying to a [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) instance running on my cluster. This works fine over HTTP.

Then I created my AWS Certificate in the Cert Manager, copied the ARN and followed this part of the documentation: [Services - Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#ssl-support-on-aws)

But the certificate is not linked to the Listeners in the AWS Load Balancer. I can’t find further documentations or a working example on the web. Can anyone point me out to one?

The LoadBalancer configuration looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"traefik-ingress-service","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"web","port":80,"targetPort":80},{"name":"admin","port":8080,"targetPort":8080},{"name":"secure","port":443,"targetPort":443}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"traefik-ingress-lb"},"type":"LoadBalancer"}}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu-north-1:000000000:certificate/e386a77d-26d9-4608-826b-b2b3a5d1ec47
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
  creationTimestamp: 2019-01-14T14:33:17Z
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "10172130"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/traefik-ingress-service
  uid: e386a77d-26d9-4608-826b-b2b3a5d1ec47
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.100.115.166
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: admin
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: secure
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: e386a77d-26d9-4608-826b-b2b3a5d1ec47.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Kind Regards and looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Have you given ingress a try? You can use a K8S ingress instead of the AWS locadbalancer and you can attach your certificate automatically through cert-manager.

Comment: I remember similar issues. Firstly, try to put the value for acm in double quotes i.e. "acm_arn". If that didn't work and assuming the acm arn is correct, take a look at cloudtrail logs it will show whether action was executed. If it was with denied access then you will know it is your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue since I'm using EKS v1.14 (and nginx-ingress-controller) and a Network Load Balancer, and according to Kubernetes, it's possible since Kubernetes v1.15 - [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73297). And since 10-March-2020 -  [Amazon EKS now supports Kubernetes version 1.15](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/amazon-eks-now-supports-kubernetes-version-1-15/)

So if it's still relevant, read more about it here - [How do I terminate HTTPS traffic on Amazon EKS workloads with ACM?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/terminate-https-traffic-eks-acm/).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and discovered that the issue was that the certificate type that I chose (ECDSA 384-bit) wasn't compatible with the Classic Load Balancer (but was supported by the new Application Load Balancer). When I switched to an RSA certificate it worked correctly.